# JQuery datepicker weirdness: can't seem to set current date in correct format

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, format

So I want to have a jQuery datepicker on my web app, which I have implemented, but can't seem to set it in the correct format. The only way to set it in the correct format, is if I don't apply "new Date()", but then the datepicker starts in March of 2019 for some reason...

Here's the little bit of JS I have now:

```
$(function () {
       //$("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }).datepicker('setDate', new Date());
       $("#datepicker").datepicker().datepicker('setDate', new Date());
});
```

As you can see I've tried several things, but none seem to get what I want. The code that executes currently will produce the following:

[image]

As you can see, the current date is set to today (february 15th when writing this post). But the format is in US style, mm/dd/yyyy. I would want it to be in the style dd/mm/yyyy.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Possibly related: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

Comment: You can see in the commented-out line in my code I've already tried that, but doesn't seem to work properly, or I'm doing it wrong. I've tried adding ".datepicker('setDate', new Date())' before and after the dateformat datepicker but didn't change anything or threw errors sadly...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4gvm8ahd/2/  seems to work fine.  Your commented line does not have the format that you said in your question you wanted.

Comment: Your commented line works for me, too. Change the MM to lower case if you want the month number instead of the month name.

Answer (score 0):

You could quickly achieve in the following.

```
var date = new Date();
date.toLocaleString('en-GB');
```

Basically, you're using the locale of the user for formatting.  In Europe they process the date as day, month, year.  In the United States we default to month, day, year.  This is the simplest way to achieve the formatting.

But the library should have a desired locale or formatting you may specify directly.  Which would make it so you don't need the above, but a quick work around is the above code.  If I have time after this meeting I'll look at the jQuery library.